# How can I use "mestimate" for detection of a new object from a live video feed?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion, opencv, motion-detection

I read that I can use motion vectors to detect new objects in a scene as a form of motion detection.

FFMPEG doesn't have motion detection implementation but I can use "mestimate" which uses motion vectors to detect objects that are moving in a video.

Here is FFMPEG "mestimate" filter:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mestimate

I do not see any examples on FFMPEG doc for utilizing "mestimate".

Can someone shed some command examples on utilizing "mestimate"?

I have a USB security camera and it is always recording the same scene and when it detects an object or a person, I would like FFMPEG to take a snapshot.

I am using the command below currently and it is either a hit or miss on detecting new objects:

```
-vf "select='gt(scene,0.04)'" snapshot.jpg
```

Thanks for any help.